# logrotate fails to rotate logs: error setting owner

Tags: permissions, users, groups, logrotate

Recently I've noticed that `logrotate` does not rotate my logs.

`user1@host:~$ /usr/sbin/logrotate /home/user1/logrotate.conf -v` gives me an error:

```
error: error setting owner of /home/logs/mylog.log.1 to uid 10111 and gid 10111: 
Operation not permitted
error: error creating output file /var/lib/logrotate/status.tmp:
Permission denied
```

That `gid` confuses me, as `user1` is only a member of a group with different `gid`:

```
user1@host:~$ id
uid=10111(user1) gid=1001(mygroup) groups=1001(mygroup)
```

However, there's another group called `user1`, but, as I mentioned, actual user `user1` is not its member:

```
user1@host:~$ cat /etc/group | grep user1
user1:x:10111
```

It's something simple here, but I can't see it.

UPDATE: here's what logrotate.conf looks like:

`/home/logs/*.log {
    rotate 7
    daily
    copytruncate
    compress
    notifempty
 }`

`user1@host:~$ ls -al /home/logs/
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 mygroup 190826983 Dec 18 06:05 mylog.log`

Comment: does running `sudo logrotate -v /home/user1/logrotate.conf ` work for you?

Comment: can you please update your question by pasting the output of these commands `cat /home/user1/logrotate.conf` and also `ls -al <log file to be rotated>`  (then format that code by highlighting and clicking the `{}` button)

Comment: are you showing us the usernames and pathnames etc -as they actually are - or are you changing them before you paste?  they don't seem to match ...

Comment: @the_velour_fog yeah, my bad. should be ok now.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using logrotates `create` directive to set the permissions of the newly created log file. To use it you

```
/home/logs/*.log {
    rotate 7
    daily
    create 0777 user1 user1
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    copytruncate
    compress
    notifempty
 }
```

From  `man logrotate`

> ```
>  create mode owner group, create owner group
> ```
>
> Immediately  after  rotation
>   (before  the postrotate script is run) the log file is created (with the same
>   name as the log file just rotated).  mode specifies the mode for the log file
>   in octal (the same as chmod(2)), owner specifies the user name who will  own
>   the log  file,  and  group  specifies the group the log file will belong to.
>   Any of the log file attributes may be omitted, in which case those attributes
>   for the new file will use the same values as the original log file for the
>   omitted attributes. This  option  can  be disabled using the nocreate option.

Comment: but what this `user1` group has to do with all this stuff?

Comment: Quick note here, `create` should not be used together with `copytruncate` -- "When this option is used, the create option will have no effect, as the old log file stays in place."